# How to turn off Play!'s javascript reverse routing generation?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

I don't need javascript reserve routing in my project so I would like to get rid of the generated classes but it's easier if it's not even generated in the first place.

So are there any options to turn that off?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Play does not generate any javascript reverse route, unless you [explicitly create one](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting#Generating-a-Javascript-router).

Am I missing something?

Comment: "The router will only expose the routes that you explicitly declare thus minimising the size of the Javascript code." It still generates but it's not exposed. I think those  are two different things

Comment: "The first step to using Play’s Javascript router is to generate it." If you don't call it, it doesn't generate anything. It's my understanding. Do you observe that it's still generated, even if you doesn't call the generator?

Comment: You can check it as well:
target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/routes_reverseRouting.scala

Comment: You are right. I've observed this behavior on 2.5 too: target/scala-2.11/routes/main/controllers/javascript/JavaScriptReverseRoutes.scala. Could this be a bug or issue? Maybe you could open a ticket at github project.